# Is there a way i can fetch nested data in my MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, material-ui, datagrid

I am trying to populate my material ui datagrid with data which is nested from my MongoDB database.

I have tried using the dot notation in the column section on my field property to explicitly point to the specific data but nothing is being fetched.

Comment: Please provide a sample document, the sample query/command that you executed, and the output you received

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.